# CMake STRING REGEX REPLACE

Tags: regex, cmake

I need to write regex in cmake lists to replace all ends of lines to spaces. I tried this, but it is incorrect

```
STRING(REGEX REPLACE "/\s+/g" " " output ${input})
```

Comment: In what way is it "incorrect"? And what do you mean by "ends of lines"? It looks like that regex replaces groups of whitespace characters with a single space each.

Comment: `string(REGEX REPLACE "[\r\n]*" " " output ${input})`

Answer (score 38):

The command expects a regular expression, but you're passing a `sed` argument in.

If you really want to replace all line-end characters with spaces, there's even no need for a regex at all. Just do this:

```
string(REPLACE "\n" " " output ${input})
```

Comment: What about `\r` ? or `\r\n` ?

Comment: @shuva Depends on how you set the contents of `input`, of course. But CMake file I/O is text-based by default, so if `input` was read by CMake from a file native to the system on which you're running, you shouldn't encounter `\r` at all.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do that by

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "[\r\n]*" " " output ${input})
```

Interestingly a relevant problem was to convert it into a `list` like the following,

```
string(STRIP ${input} stripppedinput)
string(REGEX REPLACE "[\r\n]*" ";" output ${strippedinput})
```

Comment: It is better to put "[\r\n]+" to avoid error message that an empty string is matched.